# Deployed Website Navbar not Working in both netlify and render

Tags: deployment, static, render, netlify

I just deployed my static site and when i open it, it works and all but I can't access  other pages I created, it's a simple html, css, js site no server side logic or anything, I used both netlify and render and both gave the same result. even the home navbar does not work but the  pages overall works fine on my local device, honestly I dent even know what info to share so I am linking my repo [text](https://github.com/AbdullahJama/gym-app)

input appreciate

the issue is specifically the navbar , it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that my index.html file was in a subfolder so when I  deploy my site  I get the result "page not found" because the hosting service (netlify in this case ) assume my home page (the thing which I display first upon opening my site) is in the root folder (top level folder) it assumes index.html by default is my home file name , but it didn't find it in my root so it fails to recognize its location in the subfolder, it doesn't look there, right, so it gives me "not found" so solution would be to move my home file name with its css/js file if present out of its subfolder so netlify sees first. sorry if that was a long explanation